Find the maximum of $|a-b|$ if the equation $x^3-x^2+ax-b=0$ has real and positive roots.
This is an integer type question (round off to nearest integer) stating: "Find the maximum of $|a-b|$ ($a,b \in \mathbb R$) if the equation $x^3-x^2+ax-b=0$ has real and positive roots."
My approach was to use the formula for sum and product of roots to equate $a,b$ but I ended up getting stuck at $a-b$.I am sorry if this question lacks context.
I also tried to solve this with the help of the AM-GM Inequality but because of the $-$ sign it was of no use.

I think that this problem doesn't make sense, Fix $a=1$. and let $f(x) = x^3 - x^2 + x - b$. Since $f$ is increasing function, $f(0) = -b < 0$ must be satisfied. (because $f(x) = 0$ has positive and real root.) But this means we have $b>0$ arbitrary and we can make $|a-b| = |1-b|$ arbitrary large. So there is no maximum.

@bFur4list I'm not sure, but I think the question needs all roots to be real and positive.

I played around with it and then I noticed it says roots, plural, so by the properties of cubics that means all three roots have to be real and positive actually.

How is this an "integer type question"?  The question makes no mention of integers.  The sum of the roots is $1$, so if they are real and positive they are certainly not integers.

I guess that was a hint that the maximum value will be an integer. It's worth noting that surprisingly the question is well posed AFTER we remove the "Integer type" sentence. But the OP should clarify what that sentence means if the answer turns out NOT to be an integer.

Let the roots be $r_1, r_2, r_3$.  Then $r_1 + r_2 + r_3 = 1$,
$a = r_1 r_2 + r_1 r_3 + r_2 r_3$, and $b = r_1 r_2 r_3$.  Taking
$r_3 = 1 - r_1 - r_2$, it turns out that
$$ a - b = (1 - r_1) (1 - r_2) (r_1 + r_2)$$
Take derivatives with respect to $r_1$ and $r_2$ and solve: it turns out (not surprisingly given the symmetry) that the only critical point in the region $r_1 \ge 0, r_2 \ge 0, r_1 + r_2 \le 1$ is $r_1 = r_2 = r_3 = 1/3$, which gives $a =1/3$, $b = 1/27$, $a - b = 8/27$.
Now check that $|a-b| < 8/27$ on the boundary of the region.

Ah this was heck of a lot more elegant than using lagrange multipliers. I was writing a wall of text out ...

For noting the simple expression for $a-b$, +1!

Same approach as @RobertIsrael, however it suffices to apply the AM-GM inequality
$$0\le \underbrace{a-b}_{=|a-b|}= (1-r_1)(1-r_2)(r_1 + r_2) \le \left(\frac{(1-r_1) + (1-r_2 )+ (r_1 + r_2)}{3}  \right)^3 = \frac{8}{27}$$
The equality occurs if and only $r_1 = r_2 = \frac{1}{3}$ or $(a,b) = \left( 1/3, 1/27\right)$.

ah clever! this gets away with not using optimization at all for the $\frac{8}{27}$ upper bound. Is there a non calculus based way to see that the equality occurs that is NOT just guessing and inspection?

@SidharthGhoshal The problem seems to be from a math contest for highschool pupils. And for those who participate these kind of contests, AM-GM inequality is one among the important inequalities that need to be used without thinking. Indeed, when I see $(1-r_1)(1-r_2)(r_1 + r_2) $, I know on the spot we should use the AM-GM inequality like this. The main problem is to get the expression $(1-r_1)(1-r_2)(r_1 + r_2) $ that is done by RobertIsrael.

yes that I understand but my question was about your last sentence recognizing that equality occurs only if $r_1 = r_2 = \frac{1}{3}$. Is there a way to see that without inspection (which amounts to intelligent guessing), and also does not resort to using calculus.

@SidharthGhoshal Ah, the equality occurs if and only if $1-r_1 = 1-r_2 = r_1 + r_2$, from that we deduce $r_1 = r_2 = 1/3$ and then $r_3 = 1/3$ and then $(a,b) = (1/3, 1/27)$.

@SidharthGhoshal The product of any number of positive terms with constant sum is maximum when they are all equal.  That is from AM-GM, and instantly noticeable if you remember it - I wouldn't call it a guess. +1

I see, so that maximizing of a product is ALSO just a well known fact in contest circles.
